# MySQL Server- update values of value in key-value pair

Tags: mysql

[image]

I want to update data `Training Classess` to `Training` using it's key `features_title_1` and also want to do the same with rest of the record in single query.. How will i do this ?

I know my query is wrong but here it is.. any help will be appreciated..

```
"update home_content set 
`features_title_1`    ='Training Classes' , 
`features_title_2`    ='Happy Clients' ,
`features_title_3`    ='Trainings Rooms' ,
`gender_title_women`  ='For Womendsd',
`gender_desc_women`   ='Nulla sed lacus vitae risus, 
`gender_title_men`    ='For Men',
`gender_desc_men`     ='Nulla sed lacus vitae."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create an array before executing mysql query
like this

```
$DataAarray =  array("features_title_1"    =>'Training Classes' , 
                            "features_title_2"    =>'Happy Clients' ,
                            "features_title_3"    =>'Trainings Rooms' ,
                            "gender_title_women"  =>'For Womendsd',
                            "gender_desc_women"   =>'Nulla sed lacus vitae risus', 
                            "gender_title_men"    =>'For Men',
                            "gender_desc_men"     =>'Nulla sed lacus vitae');
```

Then you can have foreach like this and inside foreach you can execute you mysql update query

```
foreach($DataAarray as $Key => $value){            
    //Updte query here 
    UPDATE `table` SET `value` = $value WHERE `mkey` = $Key;
}
```

Comment: Glad to help ... :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use case clauses to do this in a single query rather than running many update queries.  Your query would look something like this:

> UPDATE home_content SET value=( CASE WHEN (mkey='features_title_1') THEN 'Training Classes' WHEN (mkey='features_title_2') THEN 'Happy Clients' END ) WHERE mkey IN ('features_title_1','features_title_2');